# Eloquent casting int as string

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

So, I'm experiencing the following situation with two models:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

use App\Models\Landing;

class Network
{
    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
     */
    public function landings()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Landing::class);
    }
}
```

And:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

use App\Models\Network;

class Landing
{
    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
     */
    public function networks()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Network::class);
    }
}
```

So, when I call the relation:

```
<?php

$landing = Landing::find(16);
$networks = $landing->networks()->get();
```

Eloquent generate the following SQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM `landings`
    INNER JOIN `landing_network` ON `landings`.`id` = `landing_network`.`landing_id`
WHERE `landing_network`.`network_id` = '16' AND `landings`.`deleted_at` IS NULL;
```

As you can see, the `landing_network.network_id` snippet, is generated as string, but is has a performance issue on MySQL due to casting.

How can I make Laravel/Eloquent create this relation/join query without casting integer to string?

Comment: What's your real problem? Because the "casting" does not seem to be a problem.

Comment: try eager loading: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

Comment: Casting will not gonna cause you any problem